# Use variable other than :id in rails 3 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to get my rails 3 app to use a route that looks something like:

```
exampleapp.com/patients/123456
```

rather than

```
exampleapp.com/patients/1
```

where "123456" would be associated with the patient's medical record number (`:mrn`), which is already in the `:patients` table and is a unique integer. I want to use the `:mrn` in place of the usual `:id`. How would I go about this?

Sorry if this has already been asked - I couldn't find the terminology as to what I'm trying to do is called. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just add this to your Patients model

```
def class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "mrn"  
end
```

Comment: Thanks RadBrad. If I did in the controller, would I have to change anything?

Apparently not! Thanks!

Comment: Ah there is one thing though, if I set 'mrn' as the primary_key, does that mean that it cannot be edited later on? My spec tests are giving me problems when I try to edit the 'mrn' in a patient record - are there work arounds? Or is this unavoidable?

Comment: shouldn't be, it's pretty transparent,  what does you test look like?

Comment: i have an `@patient` variable (created by factory girl) and  `@patient_attr` which has the new set of values to be updated, then I call `put :update, :id => @patient.id, :patient => @patient_attr`, with the expectation that I will be redirected to the updated patient_path(@patient). However this fails, in both the tests and actual app. It looks like the 'mrn' isnt being updated (but when I change other fields the update is successful).

Comment: well, you're no longer using id, so you should make it @patient.mrn.

Answer (score 6):

You could do this,

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "mrn"
end
```

However, this will change a bunch of other things.  The to_params will use mrn.  The controller will still use params["id"], but the value will be the mrn field.  The Patient.find method will work on the mrn field, but not the id field.  (You can user Patient.find_by_mrn and Patient.find_by_id which will work on their specified fields.)  Also, all foreign keys will be to the mrn value.

You can edit the mrn field, and you will still have an id field (unless you turn it off), however, editing could be a pain because all the foreign keys will have to be corrected.

Alternatively, if you just want to change the URL, then in your config/routes.rb file instead of

```
resources :patient
```

use

```
match "/patients/:mrn" => "patients#show"
match "/patients/:mrn" => "patients#update", :via => :put
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get per-resource identifier customization by redefining the member_scope and nested_scope methods on the Resource instance.

```
resources :patients do
  @scope[:scope_level_resource].tap do |u|
    def u.member_scope
      "#{path}/:mrn"
    end

    def u.nested_scope
      "#{path}/:#{singular}_mrn"
    end
  end
end
```